# Windows 10 audio playback and recording issues

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, audio-recording

I just noticed today that my audio playback and recording aren't working as of a recent update (about 2-3 days ago, I believe). I had updated some device drivers, and now I am getting a couple of troublesome errors; although, since I hadn't used my laptop for a couple of days, I can't guarantee that these updates are actually the root of the errors.

When I try troubleshooting the audio playback, I get the errors "Audio Enhancement didn't load" and "Audio Services not responding"; however, the troubleshooter cannot seem to fix these errors. When I try to access any playback devices I am first greeted by popup windows stating "Windows has detected that audio enhancements for the following device are causing problems..." for each of my playback devices. Next, when I right click on a device from the list and click "Test", an error popup appears stating "Failed to play test tone.".

I have tried:

- Restoring my laptop (there was only one available restore point, but
  I am pretty sure it was before I installed the driver updates).
- Uninstalling all drivers under "Audio inputs and outputs" and "Sound,
  video and game controllers" then restarting.
- Checking for driver updates.
- Disabling all audio enhancements for playback devices.
- Running the "sfc /scannow" command from command prompt as an
  administrator.
- Running the Windows audio playback troubleshooter.

And I can't think of anything else to try.. I suppose I should also mention that I am running Windows 10 x64 with Realtek HD Audio.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that Windows 10 from time to time (more especificaly when the updates arrive) changes the audio driver and puts one that he thinks is better (and is not).

In my case (DELL Lattitude E5530) I have solved it downloading the appropriate driver and when it occur, I reinstall it.

There is no other problem neither other solution, you only need the appropiate driver and keep it in a known place for those ocasions.